# Odoo fixed checkbox

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

i'm creating fixed value to be view in my checkbox
First i create new model containing those value

```
request = fields.Selection(
    [('t1', 'Test1'),
     ('t2', 'Test2'),
     ('t3', 'Test3'),
     ('t4', 'Test4'),
     ('t5', 'Test5'),
    string='Request')
```

Then i added Many2many field python file :

```
req = fields.Many2many('test.request', string="Request")
```

xml file:

```
<field name="req" widget="many2many_tags">
```

but still didn't show in my view i need it to be view as checkbox containing Test1,2,...etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to create records in new model with the required data.
For example: Record1: Test1 , Record2: Test2 and so on and then use many2many field.

```
req = fields.Many2many('test.request', string="Request")
```

and for checkbox you can use widget: many2many_checkboxes widget

```
<field name="req" widget="many2many_checkboxes">
```

for selection field:

```
request = fields.Selection(
    [('t1', 'Test1'),
     ('t2', 'Test2'),
     ('t3', 'Test3'),
     ('t4', 'Test4'),
     ('t5', 'Test5'),
    string='Request')
```

xml:

```
<field name="request">
```

Comment: yes i change it but the problem it show me empty field

Comment: Have you added a security file and records in that model? As same is working for me.

Comment: for test.request module does it need to have xml tree view and form because i only want to show the value for checkbox ?

Comment: How you're creating a record if you don't have a view?

Comment: sorry but i'm new to odoo , my aim is to show it to the user as test 1,test 2 and he choose from selection value i don't want to insert it in db is that possible ?

Comment: If you want configurable selection data then it is not possible. But if you have a pre-defined list of data then you can simply use Selection field instead of many2many.

Comment: I've updated my answer of selection field too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234555/discussion-between-himanshu-sharma-and-mira).

Comment: so it's not possible, but the problem is that i need to select multiple value which is not possible by using fields.Selection As i know!

Comment: Yes, it is not possible to select many values using ``Selection`` field.